# how to include third framework on robovm ios?

Tags: robovm

We are developing game on robovm ios, it is easy to include system framework in robovm.xml.

how to include third framework on robovm ios?
Any information will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 5):

Specify the path of the framework using the `<frameworkPaths>` element in your `robovm.xml`file. Below is an example for the GooglePlus framework. This assumes that the `google-plus-ios-sdk-1.4.1` folder is located in the same folder as the `robovm.xml` file.

```
<config>
  ...
  <frameworkPaths>
    <!-- Relative path to the folder containing the
         GooglePlus.framework folder -->
    <path>google-plus-ios-sdk-1.4.1</path>
  </frameworkPaths>
  <frameworks>
    <framework>GooglePlus</framework>
  </frameworks>
  ...
</config>
```

Also note that you may have to add a `<resource>` to your `robovm.xml` file if the framework also includes image files and other resources that have to be included in your application.